# Bash refuses to execute correct binary

Tags: 12.04, bash, filesystem, latex

I've installed the current version of texlive (2012), which installs its binaries into `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux/`. I subsequently added this directory to the PATH variable by modifying the `/etc/environment` file, since I want this installed for all users:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux"
```

I then proceeded to remove the `texlive` apt-suite packages, since I was getting errors when trying to compile `.tex` documents that showed me a texlive 2009 distribution came prepackaged with my Lubuntu 12.04.

Now something pretty strange happens:

```
~ which pdflatex
/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/i386-linux/pdflatex
```

So it seems the binary is being found. Still, the following happens:

```
~ pdflatex foo.tex
/usr/bin/pdflatex: File not found!
```

Why is it looking ìn `/usr/bin/`? Is this some kind of `bash` internal cache for binary locations (I vaguely remember hearing something about this)?

What would be a possible fix?

Comment: what does `type -a pdflatex` show?

Comment: see  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very likely `/usr/bin/pdflatex` is a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the package you just removed, which in turn doesn't exist. Try `ls -l /usr/bin/pdflatex` to see if it points to another file. If it's a broken symlink (the target doesn't exist) you can simply remove it and the next `pdflatex` in the `PATH` should be run.

`which` actually looks for the first executable in the `PATH` which *exists*. In other words, if you `ln -s /non-existing/path /usr/local/sbin/pdflatex` it will be ignored by `which`, even though `/usr/local/sbin` is first in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 7):

Bash has indeed a "cache" for recently looked up programs. You can use `hash -r` to clear this cache in a shell. Alternatives:

- Just close the current shell and open a new one.
- Supply the full path, for example: `/usr/bin/pdflatex file.tex`

`which` is an external program. It will always report the program as matched in the current state. To investigate which command is executed by the shell, use the `type` builtin.

Demonstration of the cache:

```
$ which acpidump
/usr/bin/acpidump
$ type acpidump
acpidump is /usr/bin/acpidump
$ acpidump -h &>/dev/null       # trigger a lookup
$ type acpidump
acpidump is hashed (/usr/bin/acpidump)
$ mv ~/bin/acpidump{.x,}        # make acpidump available in PATH
$ which acpidump 
/home/peter/bin/acpidump
$ type acpidump 
acpidump is hashed (/usr/bin/acpidump)
$ hash -r                # clear cache
$ type acpidump 
acpidump is /home/peter/bin/acpidump
```